# Computing a p-value using the ratios of the means and ratios of the variances

Tags: t-test, p-value, descriptive-statistics

When you have a ratio of the means ($\mu_1/\mu_2$) and ratio of the variances ($\sigma^2_1/\sigma^2_2$) from two distributions, how can you compute the p-value telling you whether the means of the two distributions are significantly different or not? So, I believe this should be similar to the Welch's t-test but we just have access to the ratios of the summary statistics, and not the actual values in the experiments.

Comment: Most likely you wouldn't want to.  There's usually a better test available.  The cases where that doesn't occur are due to special restrictions on the distributions.  What exactly are you assuming about them?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  Consider $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = 100$ vs $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2 = 0.01$; clearly in the first case the variability of $\bar{x_1}/\bar{x_2}$ will be a lot greater than in the second case, but you have no way of knowing that if all you see is the ratio of the sample variances.